# Removing padded data

Tags: c, padding

I have a `char nom[100];` but when a `nom`'s size is less than 100 I have to use padding.
I use the char '.' to proceed.
But when I read data I see for example `a.txt..............................................................................................`

How can I do to remove the padded '.' in C ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either initialize your char *nom, like this:

```
char nom[100] = {'\0'};
```

Or insert a '\0' after the length you want the string "nom" to have, like this:

```
nom[5] = '\0'
```

Comment: Thanks, It's what I want to do. In a tar file it's padded with \0 and I was searching to do the same thing. Now I initialize with {'\0'}; and it's doing what I want, and it's nice !

Comment: You're very welcome! It's not much long ago since I learned this kind of initialization was available in C. Had to make it to C++ before using it in C.

Answer (score 0):

you wanna TRIM the string at the ending:

```
int i
int paddedLength=strlen(str);
int realLength = paddedLength;
char padChar = '.';

for(i=paddedLength-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if(str[i]!=padChar)
        break;
    realLength--;
}
str[realLength+1] = '\0';
```

- typed inline, no guarantees BUT the general approach works